# JSLint 2 - How can I ignore multiple function parameters

Tags: jslint

In JSLint 2, unparam is gone. Insteady, you may name a function parameter 'ignore' and the linter will ignore its unused state.

The problem I can't solve: How do I ignore multiple function parameters? Here's what I'm looking to replace:

```
       $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function (ignore_ev, ignore_current, ignore_previous, rejection) {
        if (rejection === 'route value is not an integer') {
            useTheUnloved(ignore_ev);
            useTheUnloved(ignore_current);
            useTheUnloved(ignore_previous);
            $location.path(ENV.uiRouteBase + '/');
        }
    });
    useTheUnloved = function (ignore) {
        return 'JSLint 2 - how can I ignore multiple function args';
    };
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't ignore more than 1. (In fact, I think we only got the `ignore` rule b/c JSLint itself was using code ignoring a param). JSLint encourages you to design to use all params- which stinks if you're using a third party lib & need to access a specific function signature. One option is to launder these calls through a custom library/file you write that wraps the offenders: `global.kludgeLib = {}; kludgeLib.$onIgnore = function (rejection) { fnAnon(null, null, null, rejection); };` & *not* lint that file. I don't encourage that, but I've gone with that anti-practice once or twice